# ionic : inherit content from master to child

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am trying to inherit the blog contents from *blog.html*(list of cards) to *news.html*(single card) . I cant seem to get it working. Here is my config :

**app.js**

```
.controller('BlogCtrl', function($scope, $state, Posts) {

 $scope.blogs = [];
 Posts.success(function(response) { 
 var posts = response;
 $scope.blogs = posts;
})

.state('app.news', {
url: "/news/:index",
views: {
  'menuContent': {
    templateUrl: "templates/news.html"
  }
}})
```

**BlogCtrl.js**

```
$scope.monitor = function(index){
 $state.go('app.news',{ index: index });
};
```

**blog.html**

```
<div ng-controller="BlogCtrl">
      <div ng-repeat="blog in blogs | orderBy:'-created_at'" ng-click="monitor($index)">
         <h4 class="title">{{blog.title}} </h4>
      </div>
</div>
```

**news.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="{{blog.title}}">
 <ion-content>

   <div class="list card">
    <div class="item">
     <h3 ng-bind="{{blog.title}}"></h3>
     <p ng-bind="{{blog.created_at}}"></p>
    </div>

    <div class="item item-body">
      <img class="full-image" ng-src="{{blog.img}}">
      <div ng-bind="{{blog.text}}"></div>
    </div>

  </div>
 </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Comment: can you paste here your news ctrl , you seem too missed that.@kiempoturner

Comment: hey @AmruthRao , its just an empty Ctrl. `.controller('NewsCtrl', function($scope, $state) {})`  ,  I get the data from this factory `.factory('Posts', function($http) { 
    return $http.get('http://128.199.85.104/api/v1/posts');
});`